# Mongoose find query result always a null object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I'm desperately trying to solve my problem with "find" queries with mongoose in my app.

I begin to know very well the middleware, I used it on others apps and work well, but on a new project something goes wrong and it only finds null objects in my database...

```
//server/app.js
var db = require('./lib/database');
var User = require('./models/user'); 

//server/lib/database.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = function () {
     mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pipeline');
     var connection = mongoose.connection;
     connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
     connection.once('open', function callback() { 
         console.log('connected');                 //result : connected
     });
};
module.exports = db();

//server/models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({ username: String, password: String });
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Mongoose is well connected, there's no error in the console. So **when mongoose is connected** I use this method (I precisely use this in my LocalStrategy for PassportJS) :

```
User.findOne({username: "Paul"}, function (err, user){
    console.log(user);                                // result : null
});
```

It's always null (and no error during the query), I also tested `find({})` to check all entries, but the result is an empty array `[]`.

Here's the User collection of my pipeline database (checked with Robomongo):

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547649df8d99c22fa995b050"),
    "username" : "Paul",
    "password" : "test"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54765efdcd3b13c80c2d03e2"),
    "username" : "Micka",
    "password" : "lol"
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check if you are connected to the correct database.

Comment: Yes I am. My database is mongodb://localhost:27017/pipeline, I tested to add the port in the address but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the `'User'` model use the `User` collection, you need to explicitly provide that collection name as the third parameter to `mongoose.model`, otherwise Mongoose will use the pluralized, lower-cased model name which would be `users`.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'User');
```

Comment: So simple that I can't see it by myself.. Thank you ! Finally I think I was lucky with my older apps because I used pluralized names in my db. ^^